# Missing dll file when trying to execute library CPP

Tags: c++, dll, linker, static-libraries

I received a CPP API for a device that I want to have control over. With the API,
I have have an additional folder. The folder contains:

- lib sub-directory with 2 .lib files in it
- bin sub-directory with multiple .dll files in it
- include sub-directory with multiple header (.h) files in it

I want to be able to use the API function in my project and I'm not sure how am I supposed to
import the library files properly from the folder I mentioned above.

After looking up online, I tried adding `target_link_libraries` lines with the .lib files but
then I received an error message stating that one of the .dll files (that is present in the bin sub-directory) was not found and I'm not sure on how to proceed from here.

I'd appreciate any sort of guidance.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I did not get, do you have a runtime error or compile time?

Comment: @DmytroOvdiienko runtime. I get a dialog box with the message- `the code execution cannot proceed because dll was not found...`. When I click ok on this dialog box the process finishe with exit code 0 and on the terminal I can see `process launch failed: unknown error`.

Comment: In this case in order to start the application you should either copy all/required dll files into application folder or add "bin sub-directory"  into `%PATH%` environment variable